# SQL agrupando saldo de produto por empresa

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

preciso fazer o seguinte, preciso montar um relatório que me retorne a estoque de produtos por empresas individuais. O select precisa retornar o seguinte:

```
+--------------+-----------------+------------------+-----------------+
| nome_produto | saldo_empresa_a | saldo_empresa_b  | saldo_empre_etc |
| Notebook     | saldo           | saldo            |  saldo          |
| Mouse        | saldo           | saldo            |  saldo          |
| Monitor      | saldo           | saldo            |  saldo          |
+--------------+-----------------+------------------+-----------------+
```

Meu problema é, não sei quantas empresas possuem o produto, ou seja, as colunas são dinâmicas posso ter mil empresas ou apenas uma. Posso ter produtos iguais nas empresas igual a tabela acima, ou posso ter empresa com saldo zero ou nem possui esse produto

[Aqui já montei um banco de dados para testarem O SQL no exemplo acima](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/072549/2), não faço ideia se isso que quero é possível. Alguém possui alguma sugestão?

Comment: Para o PostgreSQL pesquise pela função crosstab em tablefunc. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html

Answer (score 0):

Experimente desta forma:

```
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('SUM(CASE WHEN SE.empresa_id = ', id, ' THEN SE.saldo ELSE 0 END) AS ''', nome, '''')) 
INTO    @sql
FROM    empresa;

SET @sql =  CONCAT('
                    SELECT      P.nome AS produto
                            ,   ', @sql, '
                    FROM        saldo_estoque   SE
                    INNER JOIN  produto         P   ON P.id = SE.produto_id
                    GROUP BY    SE.produto_id');

PREPARE stmt 
FROM    @sql;

EXECUTE stmt;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Pode precisar de alguns *tweaks* porque apenas validei a estrutura, não o resultado.

Comment: essa solução é focada no mysql? vou testar mais tarde

Comment: Sim, para MySQL.